# two or more values in one row of selectbox javascript

Tags: php, javascript, drop-down-menu

In a form I need to put 2 values for each row of a select input like here:

```
<select name="amount" id="txtAmount" class="sbox" style="width: 260px;">
<option value="34.00" kredit="3000">30.00 kreditov = 34.00 €   (1.13 €/kredit)</option>
<option value="19.75" kredit="1660">16.60 kreditov = 19.75 €   (1.19 €/kredit)</option>
<option value="48.00" kredit="5000">50.00 kreditov = 48.00 €   (0.96 €/kredit)</option>
</select>
```

Now I want to get kredit value with PHP:

```
echo 'kredit: '.$_REQUEST['???.kredit']';
echo 'amount: '.$_REQUEST['amount']';
```

The amount works, but kredit does not works.

How can I get kredit value in amount selectbox?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `name` property of `select` tag means the name of a query parameter, and `value` of `option` tag is the value. Store the `kredit` values in your server.

Comment: In addition, using bare values `19.75` or `1660` can be dangerous because query parameters can be easily forged. Instead, make name for each of them, like `standard`, `light`, `full` and then find the values in server.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot submit two values via the option tag as the `value` attribute is the only value that will be submitted.

With this said, you may not even want to do so. From what I can tell, the `$kredit` variable holds the value of the users credit. This could easily be modified client side and allow for additional credit to be set.

Nevertheless, you could place both values within the `value` attribute, with a delimiter to separate the values.

```
<option value="<?php echo $amount .'-' . $kredit; ?>">Display name</option>
```

This would require you to separate them once the form is posted.

```
$values = explode('-', $_POST['amount']);
echo $values[0]; // Amount
echo $values[1]; // Kredit
```

The other option would be a `Javascript` event that would populate another hidden element when the user selects the required option.

Comment: yes, explode options is acceptable, ok, thankyou for your ansver.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a hidden `input` field with `name='kredit`'?

```
<input type='hidden' name='kredit' id='kredit'/>
```

The hidden kredit field will be submitted to the server.

```
var select = document.getElementById('txtAmount');
select.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var kredit = this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('kredit');
    document.getElementById('kredit').value = kredit;
    alert(document.getElementById('kredit').value);
});
```

This allows you to get the selected option's kredit attribute using:

```
$_REQUEST['kredit']
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4femP/)**